# How to find invalid values in a continuous signal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, floating-point

**Problem**

I have some floating point arrays where I need to identify the indexes where the values freeze, where the array has the same value for a period.

**Example**

```
x = np.linspace( 0, 30, 1000 )
y1 = np.sin( x )
y2 = np.sin( x )
# Introduce some errors!
y2[ (x>5)&(x<=8) ] = -0.2
y2[ (x>15)&(x<=16) ] = -1
y2[ (x>16)&(x<17) ] = 1
```

`y1` and `y2` look like this:

[image]

And I want to know where those horizontal lines are.

---

**I have tried**

- Loop:

  ```
  error = np.zeros_like( y2 )
  for i in range(1,y2.shape[-1]-1):
      if y2[i-1] == y2[i] == y2[i+1]:
          error[i-1] = 1
          error[i] = 1
          error[i+1] = 1
  ```

Of course I can define a window length before the `for`... But it feels clumsy as soon as I have several nested loops, for different columns and periods.

- `np.diff` → The problem here is that sometimes the derivative is 0 by itself. Also, it is common that the signal changes very slowly (temperature), so I end up checking for adjacent (zero-) values in a loop again.
- I started looking for some indexing like: `y2[ where(y2==previous(y2) & y2 == next(y2) ]`, but haven't succeeded so far. This is what I am trying now, with `pandas.DataFrame`.

I would like to have either the indexes where the horizontal lines appear, or maybe replace them with `np.nan`. I also need to be able to play a bit with the window width (will be most probably around 10 values in the end).

Any ideas?

---

**Context**

What I actually have is a `pandas.DataFrame` with temperature measurements, where I get floating point values along with timestamps of the recording time. Sometimes the error seems to "freeze" and gives a straight line instead of the measurements. Sometimes it is the last measurement repeated, sometimes it's just a random value. I need to know when each sensor failed. Of course, the duration of the failures is different every time. Each signal is about 30,000 elements long.

---

Using:    python 3.5.2    numpy 1.11.1    pandas 0.18.1

Comment: how about `np.isclose(np.diff(y2), 0)`? this has a tolerance param `rtol`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html

Comment: The erroneous values are exactly the same, `isclose()` would throw many false positives.

Comment: Not relevant to the question, just FYI: `y2[ np.ma.masked_where( (x>5)&(x<=8), y2 ).mask ] = -0.2` can be simplified to `y2[(x > 5) & (x <= 8)] = -0.2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just do something like

```
dy2 = np.r_[1, np.diff(y2).astype(bool).astype(int), 1]
bnds = np.diff(dy2)
starts = np.where(bnds == -1)[0]
stops = np.where(bnds == 1)[0] + 1
keep = stops >= starts + min_length
starts = starts[keep]
stops = stops[keep]
```

Comment: Yeah, nice trick with the data types and `diff`! I packed it into a function and am using it already, thanks! :)

Comment: BTW, I added a couple of lines at the end (just for reference):     `error = np.zeros_like( array )`
    `for a, b in zip(starts, stops):`
        `error[ a:b ] = 1`
    `assert error.shape == array.shape`
    `return error`

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, did you check the boundaries are accurate? I wasn't 100% sure. My hunch is the stops might be one point off.

Comment: Yes, the end boundary falls short by one element, it can be: `stops = np.where(bnds == 1)[0] + 1` to include the last "bad" element.